# Ruby & Syslog & custom facility

Tags: ruby, syslog

I am very new playing with syslog.

We have decided to use syslog to track some special events in our Rails application.

The problem is that I don't want to use the default `/var/log/system.log` file but use a custom one like `/var/log/myapp_events.log`.

I see that for that I have to define my own facility in `/etc/syslog.conf` like this:

```
myapp_events.* /var/log/myapp_events.log
```

After restarting syslogd I see that I can play with it directly into the **bash console**:

```
syslog -s -k Facility myapp_events Message "this is my message"
```

The message appears into the `/var/log/myapp_events.log` as expected, but I cannot reproduce this behavior using the **syslog ruby gem**. I have tried:

```
require 'syslog'
Syslog.open('myapp_events', Syslog::LOG_PID | Syslog::LOG_CONS) { |s| s.warning 'this is my message' }  # sends the message to system.log
Syslog.open('myapp_events', Syslog::LOG_PID | Syslog::LOG_CONS, 'myapp_events') { |s| s.warning 'this is my message' }  # error because 'myapp_event' can't be converted to int.
```

I see that `Syslog.open` has a third argument which is the **facility** but it has to be an integer and what I have is a string.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm seeing that the ruby `syslog` gem uses the `syslog` C implementation and this C function only accepts integer as **facility** value: http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/syslog_003b-vsyslog.html#syslog_003b-vsyslog

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Definitely the `syslog` ruby implementation doesn't allow us to use **custom facilities**.

The `syslog` ruby implementation is using the `syslog` [C implementation] (http://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/syslog/syslog.c#L36).

The `syslog` C implementation only allows us to use a very short list of facility names: `LOG_USER, LOG_MAIL, LOG_DAEMON, LOG_AUTH, LOG_SYSLOG, LOG_LPR, LOG_NEWS, LOG_UUCP, UUCP , LOG_CRON, LOG_AUTHPRIV, LOG_FTP, LOG_LOCAL0, LOG_LOCAL1, LOG_LOCAL2, LOG_LOCAL3, LOG_LOCAL4, LOG_LOCAL5, LOG_LOCAL6, LOG_LOCAL7`.

So in the end what I did was to use one of the `LOG_LOCALX` facilities that are already there for personal use.

Now I can configure syslog like this:

```
# /etc/syslog.conf
local5.*    /var/log/myapp_events.log
```

And in Ruby do this:

```
Syslog.open('myapp', Syslog::LOG_PID, Syslog::LOG_LOCAL5) { |s| s.info 'this is my message' }
```

I think is the way that `syslog` wants you to define **custom facilities**.

Comment: For those wanting to use Syslog::Logger and on < Ruby 2.1, you can use `Syslog::Logger.syslog = Syslog.open('myapp', Syslog::LOG_PID, Syslog::LOG_LOCAL5); my_logger = Syslog::Logger.new` to set the facility.

Answer (score 3):

Logger isn't useful when you have multiple workers or threads, since the log messages get interleaved.  This is why the default logger in Rails 3 is BufferedLogger.

This is also why you must use a buffering syslogger like rsyslog, or it will kill your performance.  (I believe syslogd uses fsync() which is a synchronous call that waits to return.)

Comment: nice point!, this could fix some of our problems of logging performance.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Lumberjack](https://github.com/bdurand/lumberjack).

It has support for Syslog as a log device, and you can specify facility as an option:

```
require 'lumberjack'
require 'lumberjack_syslog_device'

syslog_device = Lumberjack::SyslogDevice.new(:facility => 'myapp_events')
logger = Lumberjack::Logger.new(syslog_device)
logger.info "Hello, Syslog!"
```

Lumberjack also has quite a few other features that makes it worth a look.

Comment: The Lumberjack syslog device gives the same error stated in the original question: TypeError: can't convert String into Integer at /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/lumberjack_syslog_device-1.0.0/lib/lumberjack_syslog_device.rb:99:in `open'

Comment: looks like Lumberjack expects only a fixed list of Syslog Facilities, e.g. listed in the source code of https://github.com/bdurand/lumberjack_syslog_device/blob/master/lib/lumberjack_syslog_device.rb -- that's an enumeration, e.g. Integers. If you hand in a String it complains..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using [`Logger`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/), which is very similar to syslog, only it is a bit more user-friendly. It has multiple levels of criticality, like Syslog, and offers log rolling based on size or age.

Comment: The point is that we want to use the `syslog` daemon, so we can use its unix features by free.

Comment: My point is that Syslog in Ruby is poorly documented. You'll probably need to read the source for it to do much beyond the fundamentals. Logger is a reaction to that and is easier to use and a lot of people use it instead because it is more accessible. I use syslog all the time but still think its a PITA and could do with a major facelift to make it more appealing.

Comment: I have travel deep into the `syslog` ruby implementation and it is used the `syslog` C implementation and there is not any posibility to send to this C function a custom facility, you have to choose between the oficial ones: http://search.cpan.org/~saper/Sys-Syslog/Syslog.pm#Facilities .. think this is the end of the history :)

Comment: Seriously? Suggesting another tool when Syslog was specifically asked for is like answering "Use Java" when someone asks a Ruby question .. Utterly pointless

Comment: Wow, timely comment. As you can see, the OP had to go to great lengths to find a work-around. I suggested a Ruby solution that is used by a lot of Ruby-based apps, including Rails, not a Java one, because, sometimes, on SO we suggest workarounds when they might be easier paths to a solution.